# Empty update channel request with Node js client (GetStream.io)

Tags: getstream-io

Trying to update a channel from server-side, but getting error `"StreamChat error code 4: UpdateChannel failed with error: \"empty update channel request\""`.

Not sure what's wrong since `channel.update` has only one argument.

That's my code: (simplified)

```
const getStreamClient = new StreamChat(api_key, api_key_secret, {
  logger(type, message, data) {
    console.log(message);
    console.log(data);
  }
});

async function updateChannel(id, data) {
  const channels = await getStreamClient.queryChannels({ id }, {}, {});
  const channel = channels[0];
  return channel.update(data);
}

updateChannel("channel-id", { name: "test-name" })
.then(result => {
console.log(result);
})
.catch(err => {
console.error(err);
});
```

Adding logger to `StreamChat` didn't actually help, can't see any issues there.

Answer (score 0):

This simplified code is fine. There won't be an error.

However, I guess you have an issue in the original code. This error is triggered when

- no change body is sent
- no members or invites are changed
- no moderators are changed

Please ensure you satisfy at least one of these conditions while calling `update` on a `channel`.

A side note, you're using `id` to query channels but it's recommended to use `cid` because you might modify wrong channel by mistake. For example, `messaging:1` or `gaming:1` where id is `1` so `id` isn't unique but `cid` is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ferhat, but that's where my pain is. The error is where it should be :) I\`ve even tried calling `channel.update({ test: "qwert", ewq: "ewqw" });` and any other data passed there, but result is the same.

Comment: Could you create a ticket in support? You can share your code there safely.

Comment: So the issue was actually with different request that was going right after this. Thanks :)